# Uploaded image, but not showing

Tags: uploads, 404-error

I have a reasonably fresh WordPress install on my Ubuntu Linux server and I uploaded an image to it for use in a blog post. I checked the path in WordPress settings and I checked the contents on the server:

```
$ ls -l /srv/www/wp-uploads/blog.linformatronics.nl/2013/01
total 320
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 22033 Jan 19 10:23 ccs5licence1-150x150.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 64195 Jan 19 10:23 ccs5licence1-300x214.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 22033 Jan 19 10:19 ccs5licence-150x150.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 71973 Jan 19 10:23 ccs5licence1.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 64195 Jan 19 10:19 ccs5licence-300x214.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 71973 Jan 19 10:19 ccs5licence.png
```

The files are actually uploaded through WordPress, so it has write access to the filesystem/directory.

But when I try to use it in a blog post it shows a broken image and when I point the webbrowser directly to the image it throws an error 404 page: https://blog.linformatronics.nl/wp-uploads/2013/01/ccs5licence1.png

From the settings => media page in WordPress:

```
Uploading Files
Store uploads in this folder /srv/www/wp-uploads/blog.linformatronics.nl    
Full URL path to files       http://blog.linformatronics.nl/wp-uploads
```

I'm fairly new to WordPress, so I still need to find my way around a bit.

Comment: I never heard of a `wp-uploads/2013/01/` directory structure, but `wp-content\uploads\2013\01`. Is everything alright? or I'm wrong?

Comment: When I upload a file using the WordPress built in media upload dialog, the files are actually put into the exact mentioned location and I copied the settings in my post. The average Linux server uses forward slashes.

Comment: Solved it by adding a symlink: `sudo ln -s /srv/www/wp-uploads wp-uploads` Still don't know why it doesn't work through the regular config, but apparently the rewrite rules are not in place.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are storing your images in `/srv/www/wp-uploads/blog.linformatronics.nl/2013/01` but your link to the image is https://blog.linformatronics.nl/wp-uploads/2013/01/ccs5licence1.png.

What you need to do is tell wordpress to store the images in `/srv/www/blog.linformatronics.nl/wp-uploads/2013/01`.

What your trying to do, it seems, is store images in `wp-uploads/blog.linformatronics.nl` but the folders should be swapped. It's the website name and then the wp-uploads folder.

Comment: The problem is ***why*** images are being uploaded to that strange location. Can you explain why that might be happening or what to do to fix it?

Comment: As you said the settings from Setings > Media is `Store uploads in this folder /srv/www/wp-uploads/blog.linformatronics.nl` That needs to be `/srv/www/blog.linformatronics.nl/wp-uploads/` OR `/srv/www/wp-uploads/`. Which one works will more depend on your server setup

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem and found that navigating to Settings > Media and then changing the  *Full URL path to files* setting from

```
http://<domain>/wp-uploads
```

to

```
http://<domain>/wp-uploads/<domain>
```

eg `http://blog.mysite.com/wp-uploads/blog.mysite.com`

Comment: Still receive the 404.

Comment: Did solve it now with a symlink, see above. Your hint was part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling WordPress to store the images outside the path of your WordPress install. It is doing that but is then not able to access them.

If you specifiy a path within the WordPress install (the default is wordpress/wp-content/uploads/) WordPress will be able to find the stored images.

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this behavior also could be, that, ***after moving your DB improperly***, the auto increment (A_I) property is missing on your tables.

> Thus, make sure you have the **A_I** set on the posts table (and all
>   others) again.